# Chords Pad GUI - I want to be able to store a triad chord and as I click a pad it plays that chord

Tags: java, max-msp-jitter

```
import com.cycling74.max.*;
import javax.swing. *;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
```

This is creating the gui for later down the code

```
public class coursework3d extends MaxObject
{
    private program1 win;

    private static final String[] INLET_ASSIST = new String[]{
        "inlet 1 help"
    };
    private static final String[] OUTLET_ASSIST = new String[]{
        "outlet 1 help"
    };

    public coursework3d(Atom[] args)
    {
        declareInlets(new int[]{DataTypes.ALL,DataTypes.ALL});
        declareOutlets(new int[]{DataTypes.ALL,DataTypes.ALL,DataTypes.ALL,DataTypes.ALL});

        setInletAssist(INLET_ASSIST);
        setOutletAssist(OUTLET_ASSIST);

        win = new program1(this);
        win.setVisible (true);


    }

    public void bang()
    {
        int Cmajor[] = {0, 2,  4};
        int CSmajor[] = {1, 5, 8};
        int Dmajor[] = {2, 6, 9};
        int EFmajor[] = {3, 7, 10};
        int Emajor[] = {4, 8, 11};
        int Fmajor[] = {5, 9, 12};
        int FSmajor[] = {6, 8, 13};
        int Gmajor[] = {7, 11, 14};
        int AFmajor[] = {8, 12, 15};
        int Amajor[] = {9, 13, 16};
        int BFmajor[] = {10, 14, 17};
        int Bmajor[] = {11,  15, 18};
    }

    public void inlet(int i)
    {
    }


}
```

the gui frame contaning all panels and jbuttons

```
class program1 extends JFrame 
{
    private int width = 1250;
    private int height = 200;
    private int x = 60;
    private int y = 60;

    private JButton CMAJOR;
    private JButton CSHARPMAJOR;
    private JButton DMAJOR; 
    private JButton EFLATMAJOR;
    private JButton EMAJOR;
    private JButton FMAJOR;
    private JButton FSHARPMAJOR;
    private JButton GMAJOR;
    private JButton AFLATMAJOR; 
    private JButton AMAJOR;
    private JButton BFLATMAJOR;
    private JButton BMAJOR;

    private JPanel P1;// Panel for title
    private JPanel P2;// Panel for buttons
    private JPanel P3;// Panel for sliders

    private JLabel J1;
    private JLabel J2;
    private JLabel J3;
    private JLabel J4;
    private JLabel J5;

    private MaxObject mobject;

    public program1(MaxObject mob)
    {
        mobject = mob;

        setTitle (" ChordPad " );
        setBounds ( x, y, width, height );
        setLayout ( new BorderLayout() );

    //TOP

        P1 = new JPanel();

        //P1.setBackground ( Color.BLACK );

        P1.setLayout ( new BorderLayout() );

        add( P1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        J5 = new JLabel (" Chord Pads");

        J5.setFont(new Font("Avenir", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        J5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        P1.add (J5, BorderLayout.NORTH);



    //MIDDLE

         P2 = new JPanel();
         P2.setBackground ( Color.BLACK);
         P2.setLayout ( new GridLayout( 1 , 1 ));
         add( P2, BorderLayout.CENTER );

         CMAJOR = new JButton( "CMajor" );
         P2.add( CMAJOR );

         CSHARPMAJOR = new JButton( "C\u266FMajor" );
         P2.add( CSHARPMAJOR );


         DMAJOR = new JButton( "DMajor " );         
         P2.add( DMAJOR );


         EFLATMAJOR = new JButton( "E\u266DMajor" );
         P2.add( EFLATMAJOR );


         EMAJOR = new JButton( "EMajor)" );
         P2.add( EMAJOR );


         FMAJOR = new JButton( "FMajor " );
         P2.add( FMAJOR );


         FSHARPMAJOR = new JButton( "F\u266FMajor" );
         P2.add( FSHARPMAJOR );


         GMAJOR = new JButton( "GMajor" );
         P2.add( GMAJOR );


         AFLATMAJOR = new JButton( "A\u266DMajor" );
         P2.add( AFLATMAJOR );


         AMAJOR = new JButton( "AMajor" );
         P2.add( AMAJOR );


         BFLATMAJOR = new JButton( "B\u266DMajor" );
         P2.add( BFLATMAJOR );

         BMAJOR = new JButton( "BMajor" );
         P2.add( BMAJOR );

        Action Listener for each chord
```

Referring back to action listener so that its sent back to the max object to play each chord through a bang

```
        CMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    CMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );
        CSHARPMAJOR.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    CSHARPMAJOR();
                }
            } );

        DMAJOR.addActionListener(   new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    DMAJOR();

                }
            } );

        EFLATMAJOR.addActionListener(   new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    EFLATMAJOR();

                }
            } );

        EMAJOR.addActionListener(   new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    EMAJOR();

                }
            } );

        FSHARPMAJOR.addActionListener(  new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    FSHARPMAJOR();

                }
            } 
         );

        GMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    GMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );

        AFLATMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    AFLATMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );

        AMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    AMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );

        BFLATMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    BFLATMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );

        BMAJOR.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent aent )
                {
                    BMAJOR();
                }
            }
         );
        }



        public void CMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("CMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(1);
        }

        private void CSHARPMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("CSHARPMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(2);
        }

        private void DMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("DMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(3);
        }

        private void EFLATMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("EFLATMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(4);
        }

        private void EMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("EMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(5);
        }

        private void FMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("FSHARPMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(6);
        }

        private void FSHARPMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("FSHARPMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(7);
        }

        private void GMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("GMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(8);
        }

        private void AFLATMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("AFLATMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(9);
        }

        private void AMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("AMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(10);
        }

        private void BFLATMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("BFLATMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(11);
        }

        private void BMAJOR()
        {
        System.out.println ("BMAJOR");
        mobject.outletBang(12);
        }



}
`
```

Comment: Looks like an awesome project... but is there a question here?

Comment: After having carefully read the question I still can't seem to understand what you are asking. Could you edit the post trying to make the question clearer, showing how you previously tried to solve the problem yourself and explaining the unexpected outcomes?